# How i can Read text file from a specific line in python?

Tags: python

I want to read lines from line 5 to rest of the line in text file.

**text file contain.**

line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10

**i need result like this.**
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` in a for-loop to count the lines

```
lines_after_five =[]
with open("file.txt") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp): 
        if i >= 5:
             print(line)
             lines_after_five.append(line)
```